How close do I have to be to the thing I Hide behind?
During a game when I tried to use Distracting Shadows I was told that I need to be adjacent to the creature I want to use as cover. The feat itself does not say anything like this:

You have learned to remain hidden by using larger folk as a distraction to avoid drawing attention to yourself. You can use creatures that are at least one size larger than you (usually Medium or larger) as cover for the Hide and Sneak actions, though you still can't use such creatures as cover for other uses, such as the Take Cover action.

The Hide action also does not mention proximity:

You huddle behind cover or greater cover or deeper into concealment to become hidden, rather than observed. The GM rolls your Stealth check in secret and compares the result to the Perception DC of each creature you're observed by but that you have cover or greater cover against or are concealed from.

I found nothing in Cover either.
Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, there might be a rule relevant here that I have not found yet. Do I need to be adjacent to the Cover?
(This is not a question about Distracting Shadows, but generally about Hiding and Cover)

The cover section details when you have cover:

If you're uncertain or need to be more precise, draw a line from the center of your space to the center of the target's space. If that line passes through any terrain or object that would block the effect, the target has standard cover (or greater cover if the obstruction is extreme or the target has Taken Cover). If the line passes through a creature instead, the target has lesser cover.

This does not require you to be adjacent to the source of cover.

Added a couple bolds to emphasize the portions that more clearly indicate that what matters is the line crossing the cover, not proximity.
